# OpenCart HTML adds quotes

Tags: opencart

I'm having weird issues with the HTML in the information page. Any HTML I type has `\&quot;` added to the left and right so the following iframe would turn to this:

Before:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/"></iframe>
```

After:

```
<p><iframe src="\&quot;http://www.google.com/\&quot;"></iframe></p>
```

OpenCart Version: 1.5.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by forcing the magic_quotes off in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/user/public_html
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

create file at root with dots: .user.ini
put this:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

and then save

Answer (score 0):

You are typing your code directly into the WYSIWYG side of the editor. This will escape all the html entities like you are seeing.

All you need to do is hit the "Source" button, and put your HTML into this view instead.

[image]